# How to solve $(a^2 - x^2) \frac {\mathrm d y} {\mathrm d x} + 2xy + (a^2 - y^2) \frac {\mathrm d x} {\mathrm d y}=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The differential equation I am trying to solve is:

$\displaystyle (a^2 - x^2) \frac {\mathrm d y} {\mathrm d x} + 2xy + (a^2 - y^2) \frac {\mathrm d x} {\mathrm d y}=0$

How do I go about this? I have tried integrating it but I'm not sure how to manage the first term, do I just integrate it twice with respect to y?

Comment: The equation is satisfied, possibly trivially, by $x^2+y^2=a^2$, but I doubt this is what you are looking for. Can you provide some context?

Comment: @DavidQuinn I am looking for the full set of solutions. I don't have much context I am afraid, I have found it on a past exam paper for my university (Cambridge)

Comment: Maybe looking for a series solution might be fruitful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite it as $$(a^2-x^2)(y')^2+2xyy'+(a^2-y^2)=0$$ which is Quadratic in $y'$ so

$$y'=\frac{-xy \pm a\sqrt{x^2+y^2-a^2}}{a^2-x^2} $$ which is Non Linear Differential equation which might require Numerical methods to solve.

But if we choose family of all Concentric circles $$x^2+y^2=a^2+b^2$$ where $b \in \mathbb{R}$ is a Parameter Then

$$y'=\frac{-xy}{a^2-x^2} \pm \frac{ab}{a^2-x^2}$$ which is First order LDE whose solution is

$$y=\pm bx+k\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$$